# Using .stage not giving desired result

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, cs3

I make a global variable equal to a movieclip

A function gets run with an if statement checking if [x] movieclip exists, if it doesn't add it.
Despite the MovieClip being on the stage it continues using the if statement.

Document class

```
public static var skinHolder:MovieClip = new test;
```

Seperate Class (function runs every frame)

```
    function animHandler():void
    {
        if (! Game.skinHolder.stage)
        {
            // if its not on the stage we add it to the stage
            addChild(Game.skinHolder);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `trace("check status : " + (Game.skinHolder.stage) ); if (! Game.skinHolder.stage) { rest of code...` what did the trace say about status? You need one result so try to avoid _EnterFrame_ just for this check _ie:_  just `//`comment the addEvent line then manually run function  as `animHandler();`

Comment: check status : null

Comment: You are adding your `Game.skinHolder` to  the `SeparateClass` instance. Are you sure your `SpearateClass` instance is added in display list first? Your `SpearateClass` have to also be on stage for it's children to have access to stage.

Comment: My document class adds the SeperateClass

Comment: If my document class is not adding it to the stage, how can I do so?

Comment: Your "Separate Class" must not be on the stage. `addChild()` doesn't add anything to the stage, it adds it to the current display object, and if that object is not on the stage, well nothing is added to the stage.

Comment: I tried changing the way I add the class, from addChild() to stage.addChild() it still gives the same outcome.  I simply want to add it to the stage and check if those objects I add are on the stage.

Answer (score 0):

The stage is not set immediately after a MovieClip is added, usually it happens on the next frame.

It is an odd way to check if an object exist though, you should do something like this:

```
private var mySkinHolder:MovieClip;

if (!mySkinHolder)
{
    // if it not exist we add it to the stage
    mySkinHolder = addChild(new test());
}
```

Comment: By exists I meant I want to check that the MovieClip is on the stage.  If it's not we add it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your structure, but to check if a DisplayObjectContainer (MovieClip in your case) has a specific child, you can use the contains() method.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#contains()

```
if (!contains(Game.skinHolder)) {
    addChild(Game.skinHolder);
}
```

Comment: Same issue.  For some reason, Flash thinks that this variable is not on the stage, and keeps adding it.

Comment: I think it's probably because the variable is global, but other than that I do not know